# Fixed element overlapping into footer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to prevent a scrolling element from overlapping into the footer on a site. I've gotten it to where it does not overlap at the top of the page on a certain element but it still overlaps on the footer.

Here is the code I currently have in place:

```
// fix the orange box to the top after scrolling a certain amount
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // get the scroll position top
    var window_pos = $(window).scrollTop();

    // fix the element on scroll
    if (window_pos >= $('#sticky').offset().top) {
        $('#suggestions').attr('style', 'position: fixed; top: 0px;');


        // prevent overlapping into the footer
        if (window_pos >= $('#sticky2').offset().top || window_pos >= $('.footer').offset().top) {
            alert("exceeded");
            $('#suggestions').attr('style', 'position: absolute');
        } else {
            // restore fixed position
            if ($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('#sticky2').offset().top) {
                $('#suggestions').attr('style', 'position: fixed; top: 0px;');
            }
        }
    } else if (window_pos < $('#sticky').offset().top - 20) {
        $('#suggestions').attr('style', 'position: absolute');
    }
});
```

and the two div elements are as follows:

```
<div id="sticky" style="height: 20px; margin-top: 5px; visibility: hidden;"></div>
<div id="sticky2" style="height: 50px; margin-top: 10px; visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // get the scroll position top
    var window_pos = $(window).scrollTop();

    // fix the element on scroll
    if (window_pos >= $('#sticky').offset().top) {
        $('#suggestions').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '0px'
        });


        // prevent overlapping into the footer
        if (window_pos >= $('#sticky2').offset().top || window_pos >= $('.footer').offset().top) {

            $('#suggestions').css({
                'position': 'static',
                'top': 'auto'
            });
        } else {
            // restore fixed position
            if ($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('#sticky2').offset().top) {
                $('#suggestions').css({
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'top': '0px'
                });
            }
        }
    } else if (window_pos < $('#sticky').offset().top - 20) {
        $('#suggestions').css({
            'position': 'static',
            'top': 'auto'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that but sadly it didn't work. Here is a screenshot of what I am experiencing, if that helps.    http://imgur.com/a/TeyfA

Comment: post all html css and js in js fiddle or codepen so that easy to understand and making changes on real code

Comment: I wish I could but it is business sensitive.. All I can say is that the footer overlaps a lot more in Firefox than it does in Chrome.